# How to optimize memory of an iOS app by using secondary memory?

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, memory, optimization

I have an iOS app where I need to use a tree data structure which takes up huge amounts of memory. I need the tree to be in memory for processing. How can I reduce the app memory i.e RAM by using secondary memory?

I can take a hit on performance, as memory is more important for me.

Any ideas or pointers are welcome.

Comment: What is "secondary memory"? AFAICT, data is in RAM and/or in Flash. Processing is generally done in RAM.

Comment: I was referring to flash as the secondary memory as I don't want to hog up RAM